# Run custom code after a vim command

Tags: autocmd

I have searched through a [list of all the autocmd's](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) and can't find one which is fired when a built in VIM command is run.

How does one run some custom code after a person calls an existing vim command, e.g. `:noh`? (something like the Emacs advice function).

For those who will ask why not create a new command to call both... within a quickfix window I auto highlight some terms using `match`, and wish `:noh` to intuitively `clearmatches()` too. Hence I wish to run `clearmatches()` after `:noh` is run within a filetype of `ftplugin/qf.vim`.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want other than using a new command or keymapping. It would actually break many plugins if there was, since they would also run the custom logic. I personally map `<C-l>` to clear `:nohl` and some other things.

Comment: You might be interested in: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev

Comment: How about the `SafeState` event? It's not exactly after an autocmd, but it's triggered when Vim is done processing and will wait for user input, it might be close enough to what you want and you can use it to detect whether highlighting was cleared and execute `clearmatches()` then. Does that work for you?